how can I prevent fontinst introducing spurious spaces into fd files?
[Edit: very sorry for posting non-working code earlier. I tested this in a directory containing only the xxx-drv.tex and xxxr8a.afm with TEXMFHOME=. TEXMFLOCAL=. pdftex xxx-drv.tex.]
Consider the following standard driver xxx-drv.tex for fontinst:
\input fontinst.sty
\recordtransforms{xxx-rec.tex}
  \declaresize{}{<-> \string\xxx@@scale}
  \transformfont{xxxr8r}{\reencodefont{8r}{\fromafm{xxxr8a}}}
  \installfonts
    \installfamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar\font=\m@ne}
    \installfont{xxxr8t}{xxxr8r,newlatin option nosc}{t1}{T1}{xxx}{m}{n}{}
    \installfamily{T1}{yyy}{\hyphenchar\font=45}
    \installfont{yyyr8t}{xxxr8r,newlatin option nosc}{t1}{T1}{yyy}{m}{n}{}
  \endinstallfonts
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
\endinput

The \installfont lines worked fine some years ago, but no longer do. If I compile this with pdftex, I get the following t1xxx.fd, for example,
%Filename: t1xxx.fd
%Created by: tex xxx-drv
%Created using fontinst v1.933

%THIS FILE SHOULD BE PUT IN A TEX INPUTS DIRECTORY

\ProvidesFile{t1xxx.fd}
   [2024/08/22 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/xxx.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar \font =\m @ne}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{xxx}{m}{n}{
   <-> \xxx@@scale xxxr8t
}{}


\endinput

This is no good. The line
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar \font =\m @ne}

should be
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar\font=\m@ne}

Similarly, t1yyy.fd,
%Filename: t1yyy.fd
%Created by: tex xxx-drv
%Created using fontinst v1.933

%THIS FILE SHOULD BE PUT IN A TEX INPUTS DIRECTORY

\ProvidesFile{t1yyy.fd}
   [2024/08/22 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/yyy.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{yyy}{\hyphenchar \font =45}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{yyy}{m}{n}{
   <-> \xxx@@scale yyyr8t
}{}


\endinput

To test, you need a file xxxr8a.afm. Any afm will probably do. I used a copy of fonts/afm/arkandis/electrum/yesr8a.afm.
I would think this was a bug, but I'm not sure fontinst has changed for some time, so perhaps am I missing something obvious here?
Edit
As far as the @ is concerned, I quite like the \fontinstcc ... \normalcc method in this context, but that doesn't prevent most of the spaces getting added and obviously doesn't do anything about the second case which doesn't even include @.

! I can't find file `supp-xxx.etx' Many other support file are missing

we can't run this code, but presumably your input of \m@ne on line 9 is \m @ne as you are missing a \makeatletter so it parses as a single token. or use -1 

@DavidCarlisle I'm very sorry about the example. but I don't think that's the problem because the t1yyy.fd case doesn't  include @. and I'm not sure it should be necessary to set the catcode explicitly. at least, it didn't used to be needed. that is, I don't think it should be adding spaces at all.

@cfr egreg thinks that's the problem and he's sometimes right, especially when copying my comments:-)

@DavidCarlisle but it doesn't explain why the spaces are added at all. I don't think fontinst should alter that argument when it writes out the .fd file.

@cfr it's not adding them, you are. \m@ne is not one token it is four as you have the wrong catcode so your input is identical to \m @ne and that is always how tex linearises commandnames with letters, with a space after, it does not know if there was a space or not in the original as they parse the same way.

@DavidCarlisle I should have used -1 in the first place. because I think the second thing you said is what I don't know and am trying to ask. that is why I included the 45 case because I wanted to know about the spaces there, if you like. that is, I don't want the spaces there either.

[getting rid of the spaces is easy enough. but I would like to know if I can get fontinst to not insert them. or why I can't.]

and yes, I'm sure it is a stupid question.

@cfr off-topic, if you have .otf version of the font family, then please try with autoinst, it is one of a nice font converting script

@MadyYuvi thanks, but then I wouldn't be able to say l3build fnttarg and leave l3build to get on with it while I made lemon polenta cake. and, yes, I have otf. this is latin modern ;).

After finding missing files and editing them, I tried with fontinst from TL 2012 on and always the line
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar \font =\m @ne}

was written.
I see no reason for such syntax, when
    \installfamily{T1}{xxx}{\hyphenchar\font=-1 }

is perfectly valid.
Otherwise do
\catcode`@=11

before \installfonts and
\catcode`@=12

after \endinstallfonts.
